# Search in a file accent words in python

Tags: python, regex, diacritics, words

I have created this function on python to extract some questions from a `.txt` file.
But this function only give me non accent words, and ignore the accent ones.
Plz help me to modify this function or regular expression to catch words with accent too.

```
def extraiNormalize(nameFile):
    file = open(nameFile, 'rU')
    questions = []
    for line in file:
        field = re.search(r".*User Input:\s*([A-Za-zÀ-ú\s]+[\?])$", line)
        if field is not None:
            quest = field.group(1)
            questions.append(quest)
    file.close()
    print_list(questions)
```

Comment: What about if you add the unicode flag? `padrao = re.compile(regular_expression,re.M | re.I|re.U)`

Comment: I change a bit my code, cause the version before was not the correct one.
So the re.compile() is not needed in this version i think.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference, you can still add the flag `re.U` to `re.search` function.

Comment: I changed this line, and still give me the questions without accents..

 field = re.search(r".*User Input:\s*([A-Za-zÀ-ú\s]+[\?])$", line, re.U)

Or didnt i add that flag properly?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution to my case, where I just edited this line and add some tags.

```
field = re.search(u".*User Input:\s*([A-Za-zÀ-ú\s]+[\?])$", line.decode('utf8'), re.UNICODE)
```